# How to pass contextual filter to a view pane?

Tags: 7, panels, views

I have a taxonomy page where different view panes of a single view are displayed. I want to pass contextual filter to only kind of View pane. I wrote this code but this passes the contextual filter to all the view panes on the page. How can I pass contextual filter to a single specific view pane? Thank you for your time.

`function intrakicalendarrss_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    $arg0 = arg(0);
    $arg1 = arg(1);
    $arg2 = arg(2);
    if($view->name = 'current_event_list')  {
        if($arg0 == 'taxonomy' && $arg1 == 'term' && ($arg2 == 1 || $arg2 == 2)) {
            $Cfilter = $arg2;
            $args[0] = $Cfilter;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition to check the specific display name

```
if($view->current_display == 'display_name')
```

Here `display_name` of particular display can be found in *Advanced Option* -> *Machine Name*

Answer (score 1):

Try using $view->current_display like this:

```
function intrakicalendarrss_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  $arg0 = arg(0);
  $arg1 = arg(1);
  $arg2 = arg(2);
  if ($view->name == 'current_event_list' && $view->current_display == 'your_display') {
    if ($arg0 == 'taxonomy' && $arg1 == 'term' && ($arg2 == 1 || $arg2 == 2)) {
      $Cfilter = $arg2;
      $args[0] = $Cfilter;
    }
  }
}
```

You are also using a single equals sign in your if statement instead of a double or triple equals, which means that if statement will always return true.

Comment: Thank you rooby for your time, Pravin answered it first, so I accepted that.